# Multivariate Regression with Multiple DVs and one IV

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I want to utilize a dataset from a manufacturing setting where wastes on several materials can be predicted based on the waste generated from the production run (process waste). Say, you generate x% of final product waste (products not meeting quality spec), then x% will definitely result in wastes on the different material composition of the production run (not necessarily same % on all materials, because they have differing usage specifications, hence differing waste %). My aim is to forecast (plan) the wastes of each material based on the anticipated (fixed) process waste. How best can this relationship be examined and modelled?

Comment: Please edit this post to include some details of your data and your objectives. Otherwise, you are asking for a treatise on all of multivariate regression analysis, which is a large subject--and there is no way to identify a universal "best" method based on no information!

Comment: Thanks whber
I want to utilize a dataset from a manufacturing setting where wastes on several materials can be predicted based on the waste generated from the production run (process waste). Say, you generate x% of final product waste (products not meeting quality spec), then x% will definitely result in wastes on the different material composition of the production run (not necessarily same % on all materials, because they have differing usage specifications, hence differing waste %). My aim is to forecast (plan) the wastes of each material based on the anticipated (fixed) process waste..

Comment: Thank you--but please include your information in the question itself. Your edits will make that information plain to all readers and will bring your question more attention. It sounds like your problem has several important characteristics: it may involve time series and it appears to concern data that are proportions of a whole. I recommend you emphasize all such characteristics in your edits and in your choice of tags.

Comment: This gives a single IV (process waste) and several IVs (materials' wastes)

Answer (score 1):

Since this question has a philosophical skew and, as in all things human, *de gustibus non est disputandum*, here's my take. One approach to modeling this behavior is to employ *PLS* or partial least squares. Herman Wold, in his book *Theoretical Empiricism* (1990) laid the foundations for leveraging PLS in industrial applications like yours. PLS has seen wide application to problems seen in, e.g., chemometrics, where there are wide asymmetries in data structure (e.g., large *p* or # of variables but small *n* -- sample size). This is because it's a variant of the many dimension reducing techniques.

Comment: Could possibly direct as to how to get the recommended book, I tried contacting my booksellers and they said they couldn't possibly get. I would really appreciate your help on this... THanks

Comment: That's a good one! It is available from Amazon.